# PrimeReact Fileupload component clear Fileupload content for custom upload handler

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I am using PrimeReact FileUpload and trying to send multiple files using custom file uploader. I was able to upload the files but it is not clearing FileUpload contents and was not able to find any documentation. Is there anyway I could clear the content and disable "Upload" and "Clear" buttons.

```html
<FileUpload name="files" 
            url={url}
            action="post"
            customUpload
            uploadHandler={Upload}
            multiple accept="*/*"
            maxFileSize={100000000 } />
```

```js
const Upload = (event) => {
        
        event.files.forEach(file=>{
            formData.append("files", file);
          });
        axios({
            method: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: formData,
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
              
            }
    }).then(res => {
       
      })
```

I was not able to find any documentation.

Comment: Please note that you are NOT using PrimeFaces (Java / JSF).

Comment: Again: you are using PrimeReact, not PrimeFaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FileUpload has a `clear` method you can call from the ref.

```xml
<FileUpload ref="fileRef" />
```

```
const fileRef = useRef(null);

fileRef.current.clear();
```

Comment: i have error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: fileRef.clear is not a function. and eslint say Property 'clear' does not exist on type 'MutableRefObject '.

Comment: Clear is definitely there and works: https://primereact.org/fileupload/#api.FileUpload.methods.clear

Comment: fileRef.current.clear() work for me.

Comment: Thanks updated my answer!  Was missing `current`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a reference to the `FileUpload` component with `useRef` and call the `clear` method like this:

```
const fileUploadReference = useRef(null);

<FileUpload
  ref={fileUploadReference}
  customUpload
  uploadHandler={async () => {
    // Upload logic
    fileUploadReference.current.clear();
  }}
/>
```

See [Methods section of the FileUpload API documentation](https://primereact.org/fileupload/#api.FileUpload.methods) for more info.

Comment: Isn't this the answer I already gave?