# Remove Uploaded Files In Prime React

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I want to show only uploaded completed files on screen like below. I can show them. No problem with that.[image] I mean I am already uploading files automatically at background. Therefore I don't want to show files which going to uploaded again on screen as status "Pending" like below    [image]

I referenced melloware solution to show as completed like this link => [primereact file upload uploadHandler change status of uplaod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76561059/primereact-file-upload-uploadhandler-change-status-of-uplaod)

The problem  is I want to remove this file with remove button and onRemove method gets file parameter as null. I think its only manipulate pending files not upload completed files.

```
    <FileUpload
  onRemove={removeAttachment}
auto
 ref={fileUploadRef}
name="demo[]"
customUpload={true}
multiple
 accept="*"
  uploadHandler={attachmentUploadHandler}
 emptyTemplate={<p className="m-0">Drag and drop files to here to upload.</p>}  />

    function removeAttachment(params) {
        console.log(params);
console.log(params.file.name);
}
```

How can I pass completed file to onremove method like how it is for pending files. I tried to read ref current values etc. But no luck

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PrimeReact Fileupload component clear Fileupload content for custom upload handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74903558/primereact-fileupload-component-clear-fileupload-content-for-custom-upload-handl)

Comment: @Melloware Actually no. The uploaded file data not being passed to onRemove method. I guess primereact only handles pending files for onremove callback. For workaround I just changed pending files text and css to show like uploaded files. And I got what I want. Thanks

Comment: You should add the answer below so you can mark your own question answered and for others to see your answer.